# Oracle forms hybrid validation

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

This is my first post ever and haven't come across any other questions related to this. I am attempting to try and create a hybrid validation type and add it to an existing oracle form. We have a super/subset type of thing going on. When one chooses something from a dropdown, there are 5 options. If 4 of those options are chosen, the data is pulled from one validation table dataset, table A. If the other option is chosen, it comes from a different table's dataset, table B. These (along with others items) are saved in Table C. Table C has a FK constraint regarding these validations. I have added another column to table C to attempt to bypass the FK constraint, but the field still tries to save in the FK column. I can't seem to figure out if I need to add a database trigger, an item level trigger, or a form level trigger to reroute the data to correct columns in the database. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your items are select lists, you would use an item level trigger (`when-validate-item`) on the superset list item to populate/repopulate the list for the subset item.

Alternatively, you could use a popup LOV on the subset item which has a query which is filtered by the value of the superset item.